# Question about installing kubuntu

Tags: asus

im new to using this os and I'm wondering if my laptop can run kununtu. I have the asus L210ma it has an intel n4020, intel uhd 600 graphics, 4gb of ram, a 64gb pre-installed ssd, and a aftermarket 1tb samsung ssd. i just want to make sure i can run this os before i switch over.

Comment: Is that really eMMC internal drive? That is not as fast as a SSD. Is SSD internal or external? I did get Kubuntu 20.04 to work (only as a test) on my retired 2006 Laptop with 1.5GB RAM & 5400RPM HDD. Bit surprised it worked as most would suggest a lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
 If you can fully install on SSD, then any flavor of Ubuntu will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely run it.

These are the minimum specifications required for Ubuntu according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB (8.6 GB for minimal) of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card
  or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- An internet connection is helpful

The fact that you have an SSD for your machine is relatively detrimental in benefiting the performance.

These are extremely universal for most, if not all, Ubuntu distributions including Kubuntu.

Comment: will my boot time decrase after installing this by chance?

Comment: Considering the fact that you are using a system that is more lightweight than Windows, it will be quicker, especially since you are using an SSD.

Comment: ok, just to make sure i understand. my laptop will run better with kubuntu instead of windows 11 that it came with.

Comment: Theoretically. Linux is typically not used for personal computers, and is used more for experimentation, however since Linux is a lighter-weight system, it should run better and faster than Windows 11, especially on an SSD.

Just be careful and note that there may be a point when it is stable, so it is a good idea to maintain a backup of your system. Also, make a backup of your Windows system in case you decide to return

Comment: ok, thanks for the help and clairfying that. i will look into instaling it when i have time. i just saw your edit. i will make sure to have a fail-safe incase anything goes south on me. being in I.T i could set up a dual-boot system or jsut run it as a vm.

Comment: It's more difficult to set up as a dual-boot, and a VM requires a significant difference in system hardware, unless it is Cloud-based. (type 1 hypervisor) More than likely, you would use VirtualBox or VMWare (VirtualBox is the free one) which is a type 2 hypervisor, which means that it gathers it's resources from the hardware.

To run as a VM, you would need more RAM. Since it has a such a low amount of RAM, it is probably soldered to the motherboard, which means that it is not upgradeable.

In other words, dual-boot or just a fresh install would be most ideal in your situation.

Comment: Also, that pre-installed storage, as someone else already mentioned, is not as fast as an SSD, but it is faster than a mechanical hard drive. It is called eMMC memory. Depending on whether or not your other SSD is internal or external, I would install Kubuntu on the SSD, but only if it is internal.

I think that you got your machine from Walmart. Walmart machines are typically low quality and inexpensive. Not that this matters or anything, you can still run Linux on it

Comment: i know what your talking about. the 64gb ssd is the internal which is eMMc. the samsung ssd i installed myself in another port inside the laptop. i know everyhting your talking about, im in I.T myself. i just want to make sure before i did anything.